# Is there a video player that can go at various speeds?

Tags: video, speed, playback

I have to review very, very long videos where there is very little movement.  I am looking for a video player that can go up to speeds to 2x, 4x, 8x, 32x.  I've tried VLC, Windows Media Player, Winamp.  I can't seem to find what I need.

PowerDVD player (back in the day) could go up to 32x, but it's only for replaying DVDs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) video player allows you to speed up and slow down playback of movies with the >> and << buttons.

There's no indication I can see of the amount of speed-up, and you may have to click the buttons several times to see a difference, but it does work.

Comment: i've always used keyboard hotkeys (my keyboard lacks fast forward/rewind buttons).  +/- for faster/slower, and i think 0 resets to normal.

Comment: On one side, VLC is cool because it can reach very high speeds. On the sad side, it only keeps audio until 4x.

Answer (score 5):

I found a way to do it in native windows media player.
I'm not sure why it was so deeply hidden, it is almost as if they didn't want people to do it.

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> -> fast forward
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> -> normal
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> -> slow

If you right click on the play button, you can see these options.

Answer (score 2):

You'll be wanting [Media Player Classic- Home Cinema](http://mpc-hc.sourceforge.net/). Does the job nicely.

Answer (score 2):

[BSPlayer](http://www.bsplayer.org/) also enables you to change playback rate, up to 4x in increments of 1% (increase with F5, decrease with F6) or 10% (increase with Ctrl+F5, decrease with Ctrl+F6).

Answer (score 1):

Just to remark that not all videos can be speeded up - actually most can't.

It depends on the encoding format and the options used when encoding the video.

Answer (score 1):

Xbox media centre (all platforms) should do the trick. http://www.xbmc.org

Answer (score 1):

Media Player Classic - Home Cinema[(MPC-HC)](https://mpc-hc.org/) should be the choice. 
By default increasing the speed the audio tone will be lost.

To fix this you should change the audio renderer to "Internal audio renderer"

> options > playback > output > audio renderer > internal audio renderer

Playback speed steps can be changed in:

> options > playback > speed step

[Iformation source](https://trac.mpc-hc.org/ticket/5919?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=f706b0f94da5272713a542acdfb082546ac88db9-1580755786-0-AffQr9gnS42PzSFTO1_UN5c6gyKPA8zeBHu-2t3QgIgswGT-cMYONt03eGwZoHMEFGkEj_k8rg7zrZNTljp_8A0-d_RqT48ljBmVQ24spUrWBYDxMoQwcdlIiO02rrLPjdhv_8k1rugf7dXbcVs9F4UMYWI1UWaoSwyfKxfo5WRmJKEAJhuZ3wSLRse7UMxFfkKQAekm0ilQnazrtfJLoIDNGEKVT1AOAuCtXMLLWXSfji2kSB23Tz7OjnYrY6q0sLi6UyocqDxM5Ke-r_7cSz0)